# Type inference for lambda with generic exception chooses Exception instead of RuntimeException?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

The following SSCCE shows what I'm currently trying: I want to write an API that takes a user-defined lambda and executes it later on. The lambda defines a generic exception type, so the user may specify a custom exception that may be thrown.

So far, so good, here is the code of the API part:

```
public class Api {

  interface ThrowingLambda<E extends Exception> {
    public void doSomething() throws E;
  }

  static class Delegator<E extends Exception> {

    private ThrowingLambda<E> function;

    public Delegator(ThrowingLambda<E> function) {
      this.function = function;
    }

    public void doSomething() throws E {
      function.doSomething();
    }
  }

  public static <E extends Exception> Delegator<E> takeAlambda(ThrowingLambda<E> function) {
    return new Delegator<E>(function);
  }

}
```

The above code compiles, nothing wrong here. But the client that is using the API now gets a problem if he specifies a lambda that does not declare any exceptions:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestApi {

  @Test
  public void shouldCompile() {
    Api.takeAlambda(TestApi::doSomething)
        .doSomething();
  }

  public static void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Did something!");
  }

}
```

From my point of view I would expect the compiler to infere the type `RuntimeException` for the lambda's exception type. The Eclipse compiler does this and everything seems to be fine, but the Java compiler thinks different and goes bananas:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
TestApi.java:[10,21] unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[INFO] 1 error
```

Even more funny: If you add `throws E` to the method `takeAlambda(ThrowingLambda<E> function)` then it works and the compiler does not complain anymore.

I've no idea what the compiler does here. Is this a compiler bug or something that is on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Java 1.8_191. It works with Java 11. I don't know about versions < 11.